# Instantiating a data type that references a class object

Tags: java

In this constructor method, I am asked to set defaults and instantiate the TimeBlock. How do I instantiate the timeblock when the data type is an object of the TimeBlock class ?

```
public class Appointment {
private String description;
private TimeBlock timeBlock; 


public Appointment() { 
    description = "";
    // timeblock = ???
}
```

Comment: just write :   timeblock=new TimeBlock()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution which is closely aligned with good design principles such as dependancy injection could also be to pass in a time block to the constructor.

```
public Appointment(Timeblock timeBlock) 
{ 
    description = "";
    this.timeBlock = timeBlock; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
public Appointment() { 
    description = "";
    timeblock = new TimeBlock(); // call constructor here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's totally okay to instantiate different objects within different classes (and quite common!) So, like Ratish said, just add `timeblock = new TimeBlock();` to your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can Instantiate the class inside the Constructor as :

```
public Appointment() { 
    description = "";
    timeblock = new TimeBlock();
}
```